# Add Several NSStrings to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsurlrequest

I have an API GET Request that runs multiple times using a for loop.  I am successfully able to create some NSStrings from this, but given that the loop, I need a good way to store it all together.  So, at the end of the connectionRequest, I have it run another method, where I add the NSString to an NSMutableArray.  However, when I check the contents of the NSMutableArray, it's only the most recent NSString in there.  What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   for(int i = 0; i< self.theNumber; i++) {
        [self getQuote];
    }


}
-(void) getQuote {




    NSString *bringitalltogether = @"URLOFAPI";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bringitalltogether]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *allResults = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                       error:nil];
    NSArray *book = [allResults valueForKey:@"bookname"];
    self.bookstring = [book objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *chapter = [allResults valueForKey:@"chapter"];
    self.chapterstring = [chapter objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *verse = [allResults valueForKey:@"verse"];
    self.versestring = [verse objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *text = [allResults valueForKey:@"text"];
    self.textstring = [text objectAtIndex:0];

    [self doneGotIt];
   }
- (void) doneGotIt {
    self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *doIt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ %@:%@", self.textstring, self.bookstring, self.chapterstring, self.versestring];
    [self.theArray addObject:doIt];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.theArray);
}
```

The console shows the NSLog running the appropriate number of times, but each time, the array stays with just one verse, when I would expect it to gradually grow.

Comment: Well what do you expect?  You reinitialize it every time doneGotIt is called (alloc init will create a **new** array)

Comment: self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; is defining the array every time you cal doneGoIt, hence the array contains only the recent data

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but you could optimize by using [self.theArray appendFormat:] instead of creating a stringWithFormat: then adding it to the mutable string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the new array instance every time. thats y ,  u are getting the last part.

```
- (void) doneGotIt {
//Create array only once if not yet created in memory
    if (!self.theArray) {

        self.theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }

    NSString *doIt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ %@:%@", self.textstring, self.bookstring, self.chapterstring, self.versestring];
    [self.theArray addObject:doIt];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.theArray);
}
```